# "isolinux.bin missing or corrupt" when trying to boot 16.04 from USB

Tags: usb, 16.04, iso, dd

I wiped my USB drive using GParted and then installed the Ubuntu 16.04 ISO to the drive using Disks (`gnome-disks`) by selecting the "Restore Partition Image..." option and then writing the ISO to the drive.

When I try to boot with this USB drive, the following error message is displayed briefly before the computer elects to boot into the existing installation of Ubuntu on the computer:

```
isolinux.bin missing or corrupt.

error: invalid environment block
```

What is likely to be the problem here? How can it be fixed?

I have attempted this also using Startup Disk Creator also and observed similar behaviour.